# How to get k prime factors?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there an algorithm that can take a number k, and return a number j such that j has k prime factors? Note: the algorithm should run in polynomial time.

Assume you don't have a table of prime numbers.

Comment: The obvious solution is to simply return `j = 2^k` which has k times the prime factor 2.

Answer (score 4):

Obvious answer: starting from a table of prime numbers, given a number `k`, multiply `k` of those prime numbers together and return the result. Assuming `k` is small enough that the multiplication time remains constant, that should run in linear time.

If you need to count the time to find the prime numbers, it should still be polynomial time, using a sieve of Erathosthenese to find the table of prime numbers.

Comment: assume you don't have that table.